# PowerShell using scope

Tags: powershell

I find myself very confused with how `using` scopes work in PowerShell.

I have the following files, where each file stands for a class with the same name as the filename (except if marked):

```
-
|-Common
|--ClassA.psm1
|--GroupB
|---ClassB.psm1
|---ClassC.psm1 (class within is called MyClass)
|-ClassD.psm1
|-Main.ps1 (a script)
```

Suppose all classes in the script needs to reference each other, and `Main.ps1` need to import all classes above, what `using` statements should be present in each file in order for all modules to find each other?

Comment: [`using` is for importing namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using). It has nothing to do with importing the contents of files, which is done with the `.` operator (dot-source), or importing modules, which is done with `Import-Module`. Your `main.ps1` would `Import-Module` A, B and C (although it would be unusual to give each class its own module; it would make more sense for them to be in one module). Remember that PowerShell is a scripting language, not compiled, and declarations are processed in the order you specify.

Comment: Here's [an example of how to do ordered imports of classes in a module](https://github.com/IISResetMe/MeasureScript/blob/master/MeasureScript.psm1)

Comment: @JeroenMostert But a plain `using` imports the module automatically when I put it in `Main.ps1`. What is happening here?

Comment: @JeroenMostert - In PowerShell 5.0 and later, where the `USING` statement was introduced, it also applies to modules; if you've defined a class in a PowerShell module and you want to expose it for user code, the only way to do it is via `USING MODULE MyModule` - see [Trevor Sullivan's video at MSDN Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/MsftPowerShell/powershell-using-statement). This is a _replacement_ for `Import-Module`; you don't do both - but `Import-Module` remains part of the language.

Comment: Oh, right. The way they've shoehorned in classes is just... ugh. They needed them for DSC but the implementation leaves a lot to be desired. But yes, as the page I linked to itself documents (shame on me) that's the `using module` syntax. Especially for classes. Note that, unless you *are* using DSC, carefully consider if you actually need classes, or if you are using them because you're used to them from C#. Unlike functions and cmdlets, they are not the general mechanism for exposing functionality in PowerShell. At least not *yet*.

Comment: My particular usage case is that I would define a bunch of classes that implement the same interface to enforce typings and all that; I could probably just make sure they have the same function name then `Import-Module` them one-by-one, but then because my modules are relative to where the script is, this makes things confusing. (Coming from Python and *gulp* JavaScript, I find importing in PS to be a mess.)

Comment: Here's a code snippet from one of my own modules: `dir "$PSScriptRoot\content\*.ps1" | Foreach {  try { . $_.FullName  } catch { Write-Warning $_ } }`. Every function is in its own file in a subdirectory (each doing `Export-ModuleMember` on its own) and the main module dot-sources all these files. I'm not saying this is the right way to do it -- it is *a* way to do it. I have not yet attempted to mix in classes. As for typing in PowerShell: it's squeezing a round peg in a square hole; it's primarily a shell language, not (even) a scripting language. Writing to an interface is unusual.